# Access system.log in directory "/private/var/log/system.log" - Mac

Tags: python, macos

Basically the gist of this script will be to copy the contents of system.log to a text file, then search through that file for a specific event and log info about that event. To be specific I have a media server and I need to log the IP's of all attempted connections.

How would I go about either: 1) Duplicating to a different directory and renaming the system.log file, or 2) scanning through and copying to text of system.log to a text file? I figure the first option should be easier since once you name system.log to system.log.txt it becomes a text file.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm trying to write this out in python.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to copy it. You can open the file and access its content directly:

```py
with open('<filepath>', 'r') as file:
    content = file.read() 
    # or if you want an array of lines:
    lines = file.readlines()
```

Just make sure you have the right permissions